# Issue trying to run javascript unit tests with Intern through a Chrome Driver on a Selenium Docker Image

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run my javascript unit tests with Intern through a Chrome Driver on a Selenium Docker Image (Note: These tests run fine for me through local versions of Intern and Selenium). So far I have done the following 5 steps:

1. Pulled down Standalone Chrome image:
   `docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome`
2. Ran a Standalone Chrome container:
   `docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome`
3. Manually installed a Chrome Driver onto the Standalone Chrome image using a DockerFile:

```
# We need wget to set up the PPA and xvfb to have a virtual screen and unzip to install the Chromedriver
RUN sudo apt-get install -y wget xvfb unzip

# Set up the Chrome PPA
RUN sudo wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

# Update the package list and install chrome
RUN sudo apt-get update -y
RUN sudo apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Set up Chromedriver Environment variables
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.19
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /chromedriver
RUN sudo mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN sudo wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
RUN sudo unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Put Chromedriver into the PATH
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH
```

4. Set up my Intern configuration file:

```
        proxyPort: 9000,

        // A fully qualified URL to the Intern proxy
        proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

        // Default desired capabilities for all environments. Individual capabilities can be overridden by any of the
        maxConcurrency: 3,

        // Whether or not to start Sauce Connect before running tests
        useSauceConnect: false,
        
        capabilities: {
            'selenium-version': '4.0.0',
            'seleniumProtocol': 'WebDriver',
            'browserName': 'chrome', 
            'platform': 'Linux',
            'version': '95.0',
            'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true,
            'chromeOptions': {
              'args': [ '-incognito', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--headless' ]
            }
        },

        environments: [
            { browserName: "chrome", 'platform': 'Linux', 'version': '95.0'}
        ],

        runnerClientReporter: {
            writeHtml: false
        },
    
        tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
    
        webdriver: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 4444,
        },
```

5. Run the javascript tests which throws the following error:

```
[exec] [10:39:17] Starting 'intern-tests'...
     [exec] (node:80584) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'VERSION' of module exports inside circular dependency
     [exec] (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
     [exec] SUITE ERROR
     [exec] UnknownError: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/b63ae473e271e0927ede8816720cf81e/url / {"url":"http://localhost:9000/__intern/client.html?config=intern-config%2Fintern-config.js&reporters=%7B%22writeHtml%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%22WebDriver%22%7D&basePath=%2F&initialBaseUrl=%2F&rootSuiteName=chrome%2095.0%20on%20Linux%20-%20unit%20tests&sessionId=b63ae473e271e0927ede8816720cf81e"}] unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
     [exec]   (Session info: headless chrome=95.0.4638.54)
     [exec] Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
     [exec] System info: host: '64d03736d73e', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.47-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.11'
     [exec] Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Based on the error saying ***Driver info: driver.version: unknown*** I tried Step 3 above (Manually installed a Chrome Driver) so I'm not sure if this error is giving out about a Chrome driver at all anymore, I think that may be set up correctly.

Comment: The above doesn't make sense, official selenium docker images like selenium//standalone-chrome have the browser and respective driver installed. Why are you pulling it down and installing a driver onto it ? And if I am not mistaken you are also installing the browser as well ?

Comment: @djmonki Hi, I thought that too (i.e that docker images like selenium/standalone-chrome have the browser and respective driver installed) but when I hit the error saying "Driver info: driver.version: unknown" I thought my image might have been missing the driver for whatever reason but yea, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Sorry for delay, been busy. Looking at the above in more detail. Completely remove step 3, as discussed in earlier comment the official selenium docker image has browser and chromedriver installed. The issue is with step 4, you are declaring a browser version and platform, which is not required as you have a pre-built docker image. So remove all traces of  the following variables with it's respective values: `platform; version`

Comment: Hi @djmonki, no worries at all thanks a mill for getting back. I've started fresh, removed Step 3 completely and removed the "platform" and "version" variables from my intern configuration in Step 4 but I hit the same error unfortunately. When I look through the Docker container through the CLI I can see the Chrome Driver is there like you mentioned, I can even kick it off manually through the CLI but still have had no luck getting around the issue.

Comment: No probs, provided an answer below, building on what has been done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Completely remove step 3**

Official selenium docker images like selenium//standalone-chrome have the browser and respective driver installed.

**Update Configuration for step 4**

Remove all traces of the following variables with it's respective values:

`platform; version;`

Also noted the proxy configuration

```
// A fully qualified URL to the Intern proxy
        proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
```

Based on the above you are declaring that the proxy is installed on your local machine, however when you send your driver request to the chrome node, the Chrome browser will translate that the proxy is implemented on localhost:9000 which is the platform that it is installed on (*i.e. the Docker container*).

You need to update the intern proxy config with the ip of your local machine which is hosting your proxy and Docker container (*i.e. proxyUrl: 'http://192.168.111.222:9000/*)

You could also update it with a domain name of your choice (*e.g. my-machine*), but you would need to update your Docker command with:

```
--add-host=my-machine:<ip-address>
```

so your docker run cmd would look like this:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm --add-host=my-machine:192.168.111.222 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

Local machine hosts file updated:

```
127.0.0.1       my-machine
```

Intern configuration:

```
// A fully qualified URL to the Intern proxy
        proxyUrl: 'http://my-machine:9000/',
```

Comment: Thanks @djmonki, that did the trick and my tests are running now, was stuck on that at work for weeks. Thanks again.